# Problem with modelling a water rocket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag

I am trying to model a water rocket to find the optimal volume of water(without neglecting air resistance).

So, firstly, I make the assumption that throughout the journey of the rocket from t = 0 to t(max height), only all of the water is expelled.
I assume that no additional air inside the bottle is expelled, and that the time taken for water to be expelled = time taken for rocket to reach max height.

So, it gives me the following equations :

[image: enter image e]

where u = speed at which water exists nozzle.

It also gives me this equation :

[image]

where rho = density of water, V(initial) = initial volume of water and V(final) = volume of water  at this point in time.
Rearranging this and placing V(final) = 0, I will get the time at which height is maximum.

Now, using newtons second law and equating the different forces, I get the following differential equation for velocity :

[image]

where v = velocity of rocket, mr = mass of the rocket = m(mass of bottle) + dm/dt(mass of water). k = coefficient that is product of  SA, drag coefficient, 0.5, density of air.

Now, this differential equation cannot be solved using the methods generally used right?
I found online that I could only use Euler's method to solve this but then for solving using Euler's method, I would need to plug in values for each of these variables and I wouldn't be able to model it.
Additionally, solving this differential equation would give velocity, and I still need to integrate again to solve for height. Since Euler's method doesn't give the solution as an equation, I won't be able to integrate it again.
How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the force is a differential equation so of course the position/velocity variables are changing in time. If you aren't solving a differential equation, can you explain more on what are you doing instead?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a differential equation, and how to solve it?  How much calculus do you know?

Comment: Voting to reopen.  This seems like a perfectly fine conceptual question ("how do I deal with a situation where the force is changing with time?");  the OP's not asking for us to solve their problem.

Comment: Mathjax, friend

Answer (score 0):

You can use Euler's method or any Runge-Kutta method for this problem.  I would do it in a spreadsheet.  Each line is one timestep.  Your variable is a vector of all the quantities you want to calculate, height, velocity, pressure of the air, and so on.  The first line is $t=0$ and is your initial conditions.  In the Euler method you can now calculate the derivative of all your variables.  You have $v=0$ so you can calculate the acceleration.  If you take the timestep to be $.001$ second, at the next step $v$ is $.001$ times the acceleration.  Since $v=0$ at the start of the timestep you don't get any height change this step.  That is OK, you just need shorter steps for the Euler method than Runge-Kutta and it is easier to implement.  Since the rocket only thrusts for a couple seconds, a timestep of $.001$ seconds is only $2000$ lines.  The calculation is not hard to write for the first timestep and copy down takes care of the rest.  You could break at the end of the thrust period and use a longer timestep for the unpowered flight as not as much is changing.

Comment: But wouldn't I need values for each variable to perform the Euler's method on? I want to get the equation for height but I can't do that using the Euler's method right?

Comment: Yes, you can.  You calculate the variables at each time step.  So you start at $t=0,z=0, v=0$ and calculate the acceleration.  If you timestep is $.001$ you can calculate $v(.001)=.001a, z(.001)=.001v+.001^2a/2.  $You use those values for the next time step.  You also calculate the mass at each step, so the acceleration will increase.  You can also calculate the pressure decrease if you want, or you can consider it constant.

Comment: Ohhhh alright thank you. What do you mean by pressure decrease? Do you mean the affect of the air expelled out on the max height attained?

Comment: No, as the water is expelled the volume of air increases, so the pressure decreases.  That will reduce the thrust and the rate at which water is expelled over time.  It is a couple more things to keep track of, so you might just want to consider the pressure a constant.  It just adds a couple columns to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Oh right yeah I guess I will just consider the pressure as constant. Thanks for the help!